# Git, best practice to porting commit and changes?

Tags: git

In these weeks, quite surprisingly, I've created and worked on a branch that was created from '**test**' instead of '**master**.' Now, I find myself in the awkward position of having to merge various commits I made, into '**master**' without including all the changes touched by other colleagues on "**test**" branch.

What do you recommend as the best practice?

I was thinking of creating a clean branch from 'master' and manually bringing over the changes one by one, but it seems risky and inefficient.

Comment: _"but it seems risky and inefficient"_ - why? And what do you mean by "bringing over the changes one by one"? - Cherrypicking? If you chose your commits reasonably, that's what I would consider the way to go. Cherrypick to a new branch from master. That way you don't break anything before merging that branch back to master.

Comment: I hope your team does code reviews? And for that the reviewer should have a clean branch to look at and gives permission to merge that. With reviewing in mind i would advice to start a new clean branch and add the commits you want on that one via "Cherry Picking".

Comment: A rebase should be goog enough to move your branch over: `git rebase test my-branch --onto master`

Comment: If Lajos Arpad's answer is helpful to you, you can mark it so that it can help more people

Answer (score 1):

## Cherry-picking

https://git-scm.com/docs/git-cherry-pick

You branch out from `master`, let's call your new `branch` `tmp` for our example's sake, `checkout tmp` and run

```
git log test
```

to see what the commits were. Carefully make a list of the hashes that **might** be useful. Depending on your situation, you might run

```
git cherry-pick <branchname>
```

or

```
git cherry-pick <commit-hash>
```

If there are more commits that you want to cherry-pick from, then you can run

```
git cherry-pick ..test
```

so the commits that are present at `test` will be sequenced and you will be able to choose which commit you want to use:

Sequencer subcommands:

### --continue

```
Continue the operation in progress using the information in .git/sequencer. Can be used to continue after resolving conflicts in a failed cherry-pick or revert.
```

### --quit

```
Forget about the current operation in progress. Can be used to clear the sequencer state after a failed cherry-pick or revert.
```

### --abort

```
Cancel the operation and return to the pre-sequence state.
```